# Is there a way to pass user data for a setter without using an extra variable in C++?

Tags: c++, class, object, setter, user-data

I'm still new to C++ and so far I used to pass static values to setter methods. Now I'm trying to pass user data to the methods, but so far I can only do this using an extra variable as follows.

Class:

```
class Square
{
private:
    double length;

public:
    void setLength(double l);
    double getlength();
    double calcArea();
};
```

In main function:

```
Square s1;
double x;

cout << "Enter length: ";
cin >> x;

s1.setLength(x);
```

Thus, I use a temporary variable to pass user values to setters.
My question is, is there a way to directly pass variables to the setter? or is there a better way?

Please note that I am a beginner in C++, therefor please be descriptive and simple. Thanks!!

Comment: `length` has a getter _and_ a setter. If neither the getter nor the setter execute additional logic you might as well make `length` public. But that's also a question of personal preference.

Comment: Maybe create a function `double getInput(const char*)` and then `s1.setLength(getInput("Enter length: "))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either set the value using a variable or you can send a value, but the thing is that if you want to do it directly, it will break the law of Encapsulation. We can the class attributes private to make sure of Encapsulation. So for that, the thing you did is perfect ✌.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to know... Is it possible to do something like "s1.setLength(std::cin);" ? i know that this is syntactically wrong. Is directly passing from cin to setter possible?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's a good idea but this works :

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
class Square
{
private:
    double len;

public:
    double& length() {return len;}
    double length() const {return len;}
};

int main() {
    Square s1;

    cout << "Enter length: ";
    cin >> s1.length();
    cout << "length: " << s1.length();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this

```cpp
#include<iostream>
class Square
{
private:
    double length;

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&,Square& );
public:
    void setLength(double l);
    double getlength();
    double calcArea();
};
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Square& s )
{
    is>>s.length;
    return is;
}
int main()
{
   Square  s;
   std::cout<<"Enter length: ";
   std::cin>>s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be a design question. Does being able to load directly a specific attribute from a stream make sense? If it has a semantic value (it makes sense at the business object level) or helps to follow the DRY (do not repeat yourself) princip by avoiding code duplication, then you should write a specific method:

```
class Square {
private:
    double length;
...
public:
    std::istream& loadlength(istream& in) {
        in >> length;
        return in;
    }
...
```

You can then use it easily:

```
s1.loadlength(std::cin);
if (! std::cin) {
    // process the error condition
    ....
```

Comment: @churill: Oops, I should have read that twice... Thank you.